# Should I use a modified singleton design pattern that only allows one reference to its instance?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class that would normally just generate factory objects, however this class should only used once throughout the program in once specifix place. What is the best design pattern to use in this instance?

I throught that having a modified singleton design which only allows one reference to instance throughout the program would be the correct way to go. So only the first call to getInstance() returns the factory library.

Is this a good or bad idea? Have I missed out another fundermental design pattern for solving this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean only one reference is allowed? Or can you allow multiple references as long as they are referencing one single instance?

Comment: Only one reference is allowed. There should be no multiple references to the one single instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a final static field = new SingletonClass() and making the ctor private, why not control the creation yourself when you pass it as a parameter to all the stuff that needs a copy. This is the entire point of dependency injection, classes dont need to call static fields to get a singleton, they instead receive the instance they need as a parameter in the ctor or setter.

Comment: After much consideration I have decided that this idea in the implementation of the design key, hence why I selected it as the correct answer. This stops it being used everywhere which what was really needed. I do agree that it should be as encapsulated (private class, package private) as possible too and other answers too could have been rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

> however this class should only used once throughout the program in once specifix place

I don't think making a singleton would prevent someone to use it in more than one place, since usually singletons are global state.

In your case I would probably just make the factory class internal to the class which needs to use it. Or simply use access modifiers to ensure its not used anywhere else (package-private or protected might be what you're looking for).

Comment: Yes the class is not hidden via encapsulation but protected by the idea that you can't get an instance of it once the first instance has been assigned.

Comment: @Graham ok then if you don't want it to be an inner private class, I'd say making it package-private could be the next best choice. I myself would try to avoid the singleton if I could.

Comment: If its package private it would not stop someone from using the class more than once. Thats why I thought of using a modified singleton.

Answer (score 1):

The question is - if sometime in the future someone decides to use this class in a different part of the program, how should it work?

A. That's fine, let them.  It won't impact the other use of it. (Don't use a singleton.)

B. If there's a good reason for it, that's fine, but it's going to mess up the first use of it (due to shared resources or whatever) so they have to use the same instance that's being used elsewhere.  (Use a singleton.)

You say that it should only be used once throughout the program and in one specific place.  If that's true because of a technical restriction, make it a singleton.  If it's true because that's what your view of the design is, but there's no technical reason to put the restriction in place, then don't make it a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class that would normally just generate factory objects, however this class should only used once throughout the program in once specifix place. What is the best design pattern to use in this instance?

If it should only be used once, only call it once.  If you wish to enforce that it can be called only at that place in the code, you can control that completely by making it a private inner class of the class containing the call.

Comment: The class is very different and long to the other class if it were contained as a private inner class, it doens't fit architecture well. So that is why I ruled that option out.

Comment: @Graham: Then put it in the same package and make it package-private.

Comment: If package-private isn't sufficient you could "simulate" a private inner class by examining the stack before returning the value i.e. Call Thread.getStackTrace() and examine the element in position[1]. You could then check that the StackTraceElement.getClassName() (and possibly even getMethodName()) match the location you want to restrict it to. That said you wouldn't be able to prevent the caller from passing its recieved reference to another class within the defined visibility.

Comment: If I do that what would be the correct way to parse the created factory object to other classes? I'd like to make the (small) factory object an inner class of the library? Should I use an interface like java's Iterator object?